# Disparity between Chrome DevTools heap snapshot size and sum of size deltas for each constructor in comparison view

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, v8

Here I've taken two heap snapshots in chrome dev tools and switched it to "comparison mode" so I can see the deltas between the two snapshots:

---

[image: unbalanced memory numbers, chrome dev tools snapshot, size delta vs snapshot size]

---

Notice that the first heap snap shot is 92.3mb and the second is 275mb (as indicated under "Snapshot 1" and "Snapshot 2" on the left). This is a size increase of **182.7mb**.

In the right-most column, the size deltas for each constructor are listed (in bytes). If we sum these up we get a net increase of about **500kb**.

How could this be? Shouldn't the size deltas sum be the same as the size difference between the snapshots? If you look at the [chrome heap snapshots tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/heap-snapshots) in the "Comparison View" section, there's a screenshot that shows what you'd expect: the size deltas sum to the change is snapshot size.

Note: I'm actually using the `--inspect` option of nodejs, so this isn't the regular chrome devtools, but it looks like it's essentially the same software (and maintained by the same team), just slightly adapted to nodejs, so I'm keeping it general by not tagging nodejs, etc.

**Edit 1:** I followed @wOxxOm's advice from the comments (click garbage bin icon before snapshot) and got a 60mb snapshot vs a 300mb snapshot, but when I clicked the mode dropdown and selected "comparison" to get the deltas I got this message (you'll probably need to open the image in a new tab to read it):

[image: An error occurred when a call to method 'calculateSnapshotDiff' was requested]

I'm beginning to think this may have to do with nodejs, and it seems like it's not just something I misunderstood about DevTools, so I'll add some extra details which might be clues as to what's going on:

- I'm using [node-webworker-threads](https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads) which implements the WebWorker API in nodejs using native threads.
- I'm passing these "workers" 10mb chunks of text to be processed and then have metadata returned to the main thread and aggregated. The text is being pumped into the pool of workers at about 5mb/s.
- When I clicked the garbage bin icon as @wOxxOm suggested, my computer's RAM usage didn't seem to drop.
- On [this page](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/heap-snapshots) it says "**Only reachable objects are included in snapshots. Also, taking a snapshot always starts with a garbage collection.**" Could it be that the snapshot size is taking into account the RAM used by the workers, but the actual table of constructors + deltas only lists "reachable objects" in the main thread?
- [Here's a pie graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PQjL.png) of the memory usage.

Comment: Might be a bug in recent versions of Chrome. Try clicking the garbage bin icon prior to making a snapshot.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the comment. I've updated the post with the results and added some more details.